# Multithreading on ASP .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I have to make a few request to get some data from third party services. As response time from each petition can range from a few seconds to a full minute, I've thinking that would be a good case for implement a multi-thread solution (as seen [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398587/multi-threading-a-web-application)) but as I haven't used it before, I'm not sure how to implement it.

I have to call 4 services, and each of them with similar parameters. Each of the calls will have a ID which I must generate and keep associated with the session. Also, I have to display information from the first call of each service.

Which would be the best approach? Any advice on sources of information (apart from SO, of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at [Use Threads and Build Asynchronous Handlers in Your Server-Side Web Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164128.aspx) and [Asynchronous Pages in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx).